# Avoid warning about static vs dynamic elaboration checks with GNATCOLL on macOS

Tags: ada, gnat, elaboration

I am trying to use GNATCOLL (on macOS) by adding

```
with "gnatcoll"
```

to my .gpr file, but I am getting this warning:

```
warning: "main.adb" has dynamic elaboration checks and with's
warning:   "gnatcoll-traces.ads" which has static elaboration checks
```

I compiled GNATCOLL, and then recompiled it with the configure option --enable-shared. Judging from the files, the shared library version is installed.

How can I direct gnatmake to use the shared library version of GNATCOLL? Or alternatively, how can I build my program statically, so at least it's compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is not about linking, but about **elaboration checks**.

According to the help for `gnatmake`, you **enable** dynamic elaboration checking mode with the flag `-gnatE`.  This indicates that you might solve your problem by removing the `-gnatE` flag from your build command.